# How to import photos from onedrive from xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, import, onedrive, photo

I have a requirement that requires way to import photos from onedrive into xamarin forms application. The ideal way would be to open onedrive on click of a button within the app after which the user can select the photos required and then import the selected ones back to the app.

I understand this is not as straightforward as importing from the phone gallery which can be done using plugins such as crossmedia.
Any leads on how to approach this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: there are numerous existing questions, posts, blogs, etc about using Onedrive with Xamarin.  I suggest you start by reading them and figuring out the basics of connecting to OneDrive and then proceed from there.

Comment: Thanks jason. i am currently doing that. Would be really great if you could share a few links here that i can go through.
Thanks

Comment: You can search for these keywords “OneDrive" "Xamarin" "forms" on your browser, you will see a GitHub corresponding to your problem, I believe it can solve your problem.